# MVC dropdownlist get text

Tags: c#, asp.net

Implemented Scott Alen's dropdownlist: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Using his example I get Id's (SelectedFlavorId) but not the actual text.

How do I get the actual text in the action method.

Comment: Do you mean at the post back?  If you want the text instead of the id, why not make the value in your `SelectList` be the text, not the id?  eg `SelectList(_flavors, "Name", "Name");`

Comment: @intracept - yes, at the post back. I actually need that id as well.

Comment: If you have the ID, you could just use EF to get the matching text for that ID in you postback using something like `db.IceCreamFlavors.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == vm.ID)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Postback" is a WebForms concept; assuming you have enabled ViewState, you get most (if not all) of the original data from the page load when you post back to the server.

The only data that gets posted in ASP.NET MVC is what's bound to a successful input. So, assuming you were using jQuery, you'd need to bind a hidden input if you also wanted the text value:

```
$('form').on('change', '#SelectedFlavorId', function(e){

    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $('#SelectedFlavorText').val(text);

});
```

Here, I assume you named the property for the hidden input `SelectedFlavorText`.

Comment: That was a good idea, thanks! (I just had to fix ($this) to $(this).

Comment: @ra170 Sorry, that was a typo.